# I want to create multiple table in sqflite by calling same function

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I want to create multiple tables in sqflite by calling the same function, cause I want to create multiple playlists, playlist name will be the table name, which came from user input,
for this reason, users call the databaseCreate function in multiple time. But its show some error :

```
     Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(no such table: sports (code 1 
     SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO sports (title, link, logo, 
     playlistName) VALUES (?, ?, NULL, ?)) sql 'INSERT INTO sports (title, link, logo, 
     playlistName)
```

Database Create Code :

```
 Future open( String name) async {
  Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'playlist1.db');
_database = await openDatabase(path, version: 2,
    onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute('''
  create table $name ( 
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,playlistName TEXT, link TEXT, title TEXT, 
 logo TEXT)
   ''');
    });
   }
```

Hare's name comes from the user. At a very fast time, it will be okay but for creating a second playlist it will be crashed

Comment: You can pass query as a parameter to the method of create table (open).

Comment: what kind of query please explain?

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer use parameterized queries:

```
await db.execute("
  create table ? ( 
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,playlistName TEXT, link TEXT, title TEXT, 
 logo TEXT)
   ", [name]);
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to update the database schema, you need to update the version of the database, like this:

```
return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 2, // <=== Update (increase) this number
      onOpen: (db) {},
      onCreate: createDatabase,
      onUpgrade: upgradeDatabase,
    );
```

Doing this, you ask SQFLite to update the schema. Use onUpgrade to tell the new schema.

You can also uninstall the app when you are in development stage. In this case, new schema should be in onCreate.

If i resume, onCreate is called once when database is created. And onUpgrade is called each time version is increased.

**UPDATE 2**

For unknown reasons (haven't search more), execute method does not replace the `?` by parameter. Perharps for security reasons. In fact using dynamic table name is not a very good design.

So for achive this, you shoult not use parameterized query like i said previously. You should use a concatened string, like this:

```
await db.rawQuery(
        "create table " +
            name +
            " ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,playlistName TEXT, link TEXT, title TEXT,  logo TEXT)",[]);
```

Comment: it does not work. The error says table name not found. Table not created

Comment: Have you change the version of the database? Or have you uninstall application?
Because, statements in sqflite create hook are executed only when upgrading database version or when database doe not exists.

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain how to make SQFLite aware of the new schema.

Comment: error DatabaseException(near "?": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE ? (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,playlistName TEXT, link TEXT, title TEXT, logo TEXT )) sql '        CREATE TABLE ? (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,playlistName TEXT, link TEXT, title TEXT, logo TEXT )
I/flutter ( 3548):           ' args [sports] during open, closing...

Comment: in args i pass the name variable

Comment: @FuadMostafij You're right, i give a try to the code in a existing projet and get same error. I have updated my answer with functionnal source code that i have tested and like this it works.

Comment: The example is with `rawQuery` method, but you can also use `execute`, just replace `rawQuery` by `execute`

Comment: As it sound as a bug, i have submit a new issue to sqlfite team.